# Coded UI Test winforms menu item identification wrong

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10, menuitem, coded-ui-tests

I use the assertion function to identify controls. When I use the assertion function for the Coded UI Test (`Ctrl + Shift + I`) the menu items in my .NET application running on Windows 10 are always recogniced at the wrong position. I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (version 15.5.7).

My cursor was at the "Öffnen" menu item but the MSAA thinks it is the "Speichern" menu item. It seems shifted for one menu entry.

For other application the control identification works fine. It seems a problem with this particular application.

What could possibly be wrong in using Coded UI Test Builder?

[image: Wrong menu item identification]

---

**Update**

I also tried to increase the [`MaxLevelsForItemContainer`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dpksinghal/2011/09/28/how-to-test-deep-hierarchy-controls-using-coded-ui-test-in-wpf/) from the default value of `2` to `5` in the `CodedUITestBuilder.exe.config` without success.

The [`SearchConfiguration.NextSibling()`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/siddharthapandey/2010/04/10/searchconfiguration-nextsibling/#comments) method didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise update from version 15.5.7 to 15.6.1 the menu item was recognized correctly. I'm not aware of any other change I did on my system but since the update it seems to work.

Solution:

- **Update Visual Studio 2017**

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with the `Spiechern` button masking the `Öffnen` button -
 atleast so far as the test builder sees it.

Try navigating to the `Öffnen` button through usage of the parent child navigator in the test builder (the button button 4 arrows around a blue box, next to `Retry` and `Add Assertion`), and then identify with the [`NextSibling()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.extension.searchconfiguration.nextsibling(v=vs.140).aspx) method. This would look like:

```cs
// Clicks Öffnen - Change NextSibling()to be whatever filial relation is required
var offnen = new WpfButton();
offnen = offnen.SearchProperties.Add(WpfButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Spiechern").NextSibling();
offnen.Click();
```

If that doesn't work set your tests up to use the identification of the `Spiechern` button, and then alter the portion that needs to click on the `Öffnen` button to click slightly above above the `Spiechern` button.  That would look like:

```cs
// Clicks Öffnen - Change xOffset and yOffset to whatever is required to click Öffnen 
var spiechern = new WpfButton();
spiechern= spiechern.SearchProperties.Add(WpfButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Spiechern");
Mouse.Click(spiechern, new Point(xOffset, yOffset));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've to mention this application is not an WPF application but a winforms application. I found a WinMenuItem but I couldn't figure out a "NextSibling" method.
The mouse click offset is a ugly solution. I consider it only as a very last resort.

Comment: Manually building the search with control name may be an option. This means that you do not use the recorder but do the search manually with a well identifiable property, ideally some automation ID. (As proposed by Rescis in second snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I wanted by using the menu keyboard shortcuts and navigating through the menu and record this.

Possible solution in this case:

- **use keyboard shortcuts**